# Cannot read property 'getHostNode' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a horizon/react app with react router and I have a simple button in my app:

```
<Link className="dark button" to="/">Another Search</Link>
```

When I click on it, I get the following exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getHostNode' of null
```

The error comes from:

```
getHostNode: function (internalInstance) {
    return internalInstance.getHostNode();
},
```

Any idea why am I getting this?

Comment: Are you doing anything special in your component? I could not reproduce it with the latest React Router. It seems they are keeping the comments. Check out this codepen: http://codepen.io/alansouzati/pen/GqPAmY?editors=001

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was facing a similar issue. It turns out that, in my case, was highlighthjs removing comments from the generated dom.

For text, React 15 is adding comment with the reactid instead of a span tag, as in:

```
<!-- react-text: 248-->
Another Search
<!--/react-test-->
```

Can you try something like this?

`<Link className="dark button" to="/"><span>Another Search</span></Link>`

This will force the generated DOM to include the span with the proper `data-reactid` attribute.

I would file an issue with react-router, maybe they can do that internally so you would not have to bother about it. But there are challenges with that as the Link child could be basically anything.

Answer (score 13):

I have run into this issue multiple times in the last few days (new to react) and in almost all the cases, there was some syntax/code error that was not caught anywhere else. One example: If you write:

```
getInitialState() {
    showModal: false
},
```

instead of:

```
getInitialState() {
    return {
        showModal: false
    };
},
```

you will get this error. That is unless your build process does not already catch the error. Hope this helps someone (or myself in a couple of days. `Hi Niyaz, you are welcome!`).

Answer (score 3):

If anyone else finds this thread. For me this turned out to be a null error for a prop.

Code generating error:

```
<Menu InventoryCount={this.state.inventoryModel.length} />
```

Working null checked code:

```
<Menu InventoryCount={this.state.inventoryModel ? this.state.inventoryModel.length : 0} />
```

Comment: Just a tip: you can use also <Menu InventoryCount={this.state.inventoryModel || 0} />

Answer (score 2):

For me, it's a typo which results in importing component from wrong module.

```
import { Link, Icon } from 'react-router';
import { Tag } from 'antd';
```

it should be

```
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { Tag, Icon } from 'antd';
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had to restart my nodemon backend.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting :) for me, it turned out that I was consuming props incorrectly in child component. Might be helpful for someone.

```
function Parent(){
    const styleEle = { width: '100px'};
    return (<div>
            <Child styleO={styleEle}/>
        </div>);
}

function Parent(props){
    // here i was directly using <div style={styleO}> causing issue for me
    return (<div style={props.styleO}>
            {'Something'}
        </div>)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you getting error like "getHostNode" of null then its a error related to old code which is written before and it comes with version update of react

we have two ways to resolve the same 
1) First we have to uninstall react from project and than again install react with the version specified( old one 15.4.2) current version of react is 15.6.1
2) Second way is bit time consuming but for future of application its good , go through the old code and handle errors(error handling of promises ) with the correct way following are few links which help you to figure out whats running behind

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8579
https://github.com/mitodl/micromasters/pull/3022

Comment: If "uninstall" does not work, try to remove "react" and "react-dom" folders from node_modules and run "npm install".

Comment: It also may manifest itself as "Unhandled Rejection (Invariant Violation): Attempted to update component `xxx` that has already been unmounted (or failed to mount)."

Answer (score 1):

I got this error trying to render `undefined` value by mistake.

```
render(){
  let name = this.getName(); // this returns `undefined`
  return <div>name: {name}</div>
}
```

The fix is to fallback to null (where is accepted value)

```
render(){
  let name = this.getName(); // this returns `undefined`
  return <div>name: {name || null}</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issue.

I was trying to manually update some plugin from node_modules, and when I reverted it back, i got this error.

I solved it by deleting node_modules and running NPM install.

Answer (score 0):

In my case React was not in the scope of the file.

If you import a variable which has jsx from a different file which does not have react imported in it.

```
import React from "react";
```

Using following eslint plugin would avoid this: `react-in-jsx-scope`

Source: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/84

Answer (score 0):

In my case, an import was missing. Check your imports!

Answer (score -1):

My solution is just deleting the cached images, files and cookies if you using the Chrome. Settings -> Privacy and security -> Clear browsing data -> Cached image and files / Cookies and other site data

[image]