# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getHostNode' of null react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react js and in my following code I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getHostNode' of null` error. I have referred to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38796376/cannot-read-property-gethostnode-of-null). But it is not helpful in my case. Below is my code :

```
 for(var i=0;i<city.length;i++){
    if(city[i]!= null){
        if(i < 10){
            cityListValues.push(<li key={"city-"+i} ><a onClick={this.updateCity} id={city[i].city_id} className={(this.props.city_name==city[i].name)? 'active':''}>{city[i].name}</a></li>);

        } else{
          break;
        }
    }
}
```

When I click on the `a tag`, the first time it works just fine. But, next time it always throw the error. I'm not able to figure out what is the problem. When the method is called, it renders around 5 components and set the state for all of them. I have applied the mentioned solution there and inserted all the text inside `span`, but still keep getting the error.

City data : `[{"city_id":202,"name":"abc","no_of_activities":1},{"city_id":175,"name":"xyz","no_of_activities":13},{"city_id":4612,"name":"pqr","no_of_activities":1},{"city_id":3,"name":"a1s2","no_of_activities":83},{"city_id":176,"name":"fgj","no_of_activities":1},{"city_id":172,"name":"ytu","no_of_activities":2},{"city_id":1092,"name":"mkju","no_of_activities":1}]`

```
updateCity : function() {
    var iso_code = '/';
    this.props.changeCity(event.target.id);
    if(this.props.country_id !== '99') {

        for (var i=0; i<this.props.country_list.length; i++) {
            if(this.props.country_id == this.props.country_list[i].country_id) {
                iso_code = '/'+this.props.country_list[i].iso_code_2.toLowerCase()+'/';
            }
        }
    }
    browserHistory.push(iso_code);
},
```

Comment: Also post city variable data

Comment: Updated the question